# GAE Error code 104 in request breaks few subsequent requests

Tags: java, google-app-engine, timeout

we experience the following error pattern:

1. sometimes we have GAE app request processing lasting long, this throws `DeadlineExceededException` as GAE has a limit for 1 min. This is a described by docs, ok.
2. apart from `DeadlineExceededException` we get `A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may be throwing exceptions during the initialization of your application. (Error code 104)`
3. subsequent requests coming to GAE app within next few milliseconds fail with the same `Error code 104`

Questions:

- Why #2 is reported?
- How can we avoid #3? Is it a bug in GAE? What is the mechanism of such failure?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you look at the logs in the admin console and see if theres an error being thrown? Often they give more details as to why an instance closed.

Comment: @Bruyere: added log to question

Comment: The error is: BigQuery internal error. Probably unavailable service or huge resultset. Theres two ways I can see around this. Because your hitting the 1 minute limit on the page maybe pushing it to a Taskque or backend instance (which has a 10 minute timeout) or lowering your 50k limit. You can also increase the size of the max return but I believe you'll still have issues with the frontend timming out. https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#largequeryresults

Comment: @Bruyere: string "BigQuery internal error. Probably unavailable service or huge resultset" generated by me. Usage of BigQuery here is a detail and is not related to question - my concern is _why_ timeout of one GAE request causes failure of few subsequent and independent http requests to GAE app. This pattern does not happen often, but still it happens (Error 104)

Comment: The two errors that follow are threads dying. If you have multiple requests it will kill them all unfortunately. 

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors?hl=en

Comment: @Bruyere: cheers for the link!

Answer (score 1):

As [Bruyere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3877822/bruyere) kindly pointed, related threads killing in result of timeout exception is detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors?hl=en):

> If concurrent requests are enabled through the "threadsafe" flag, every other running concurrent request is killed with error code 104: